# How to avoid a column for grouping when I am using group by clause

Tags: jquery, sql, postgresql, group-by

I would like to remove one column from grouping as it is giving wrong outcome when I am using group by clause.

Here is the query

```
select co.documentNo as documentno
      , mproduct.upc as upc
      , mproduct.name as itemcode
      , mproduct.em_cl_modelname as modelname
      , sum(prod.quantity) as quantity 
from OBWPACK_Box box
,OBWPACK_Movlinebox prod
,packingh header
,partner partner
,product mproduct
,order co
,orderline col
,m_inout minout 
where box.packingh_id=header.packingh_id
  and prod.obwpack_box_id=box.obwpack_box_id 
  and partner.partner_id=header.partner_id 
  and mproduct.product_id=prod.product_id 
  and  col.order_id=co.order_id 
  and col.orderline_id=prod.orderline_id 
  and co.order_id=minout.order_id 
  and minout.docstatus='CO'
  and box.trackingNo='EDGER'
  and partner.name='102' 
group by prod.quantity,mproduct.name,mproduct.em_cl_modelname,mproduct.upc, co.documentNo
```

result is

```
document         upc        itemcode    sum
I1001717    3583782495440   1132004      1
1001717     3583788674153   1719722      2
1001717     3583788674153   1719722      5
```

But I would like to get as below

```
document         upc        itemcode        sum
I1001717    3583782495440   1132004          1
1001717     3583788674153   1719722          7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `prod.quantity` from `Group by`

```
SELECT co.documentNo            AS documentno,
       mproduct.upc             AS upc,
       mproduct.NAME            AS itemcode,
       mproduct.em_cl_modelname AS modelname,
       Sum(prod.quantity)       AS quantity
FROM   OBWPACK_Box box,
       OBWPACK_Movlinebox prod,
       packingh header,
       partner partner,
       product mproduct,
       order co,
       orderline col,
       m_inout minout
WHERE  box.packingh_id = header.packingh_id
       AND prod.obwpack_box_id = box.obwpack_box_id
       AND partner.partner_id = header.partner_id
       AND mproduct.product_id = prod.product_id
       AND col.order_id = co.order_id
       AND col.orderline_id = prod.orderline_id
       AND co.order_id = minout.order_id
       AND minout.docstatus = 'CO'
       AND box.trackingNo = 'EDGER'
       AND partner.NAME = '102'
GROUP  BY mproduct.NAME,
          mproduct.em_cl_modelname,
          mproduct.upc,
          co.documentNo
```